# Linq Query Distinct Function do not work with DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

> I want to assign Linq Query result to dropdownlist which contain a
>   Distinct function

My Code:-

```
var area = de.City_Area_View
                        .Select(m => new { m.Area_Id, m.Area_Name})
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();

            drpfilter.DataTextField = "Area_Name";
            drpfilter.DataValueField = "Area_Id";
            drpfilter.DataSource = area;
            drpfilter.DataBind();
```

Problem :- When I write this code then I get Below Error

> Error:- The method 'Distinct' is not supported.

I get `System.NotSupportedException`.

I want to assign a Distinct name of area to the DropDownList 
So please help me for this problem.

Comment: What is your underlying data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your set is small enough (so you don't mind fetching *all* the values from the database), the simplest thing would be to force the distinct part to be performed locally:

```
var area = de.City_Area_View
             .Select(m => new { m.Area_Id, m.Area_Name})
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Distinct()
             .ToList();
```

`AsEnumerable` simply "changes" the expression type to `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`, so that the compiler calls `Enumerable.Distinct` instead of `Queryable.Distinct` - and `Enumerable.Distict` will definitely work.